# Argument parser does not accept my data file

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Running python 2.7.5 in [Spyder](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/), trying to set up an argument parser to import input from a file called `data.csv` in the same folder as my script. Currently, this part of my function looks like so:

```
from sys import argv
from argparse import ArgumentParser
def ParseArguments():

    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Description of program')

    parser.add_argument("-f", type=str, dest="data", 
                    default="", help="Input file", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-o", type=str, dest="output_file", 
                    default="", help="Output file")
    parser.add_argument("-p", type=float, dest="first_parameter", 
                    default=0.5, help="First Parameter (decimal)")
    parser.add_argument("-n", type=int, dest="second_parameter", 
                    default=0, help="Second Parameter (integer)")

    args = parser.parse_args()

def my_function(args):
    print "Input file is:", args.data
    print "Output file is:", args.output_file
    print "Parameter 1 is:", args.first_parameter
    print "Parameter 2 is:", args.second_parameter
```

Then I call it in my main function:

```
def main(argv):
    args = ParseArguments()
    my_function(args)
    args.data
def read(data):
    fh = read(args.data, "data")
    (...)
```

Now, when I try to run this I get the error message:

```
runfile('C:filepath', wdir='C:/filepath')
usage: code.py [-h] -f DATA [-o OUTPUT_FILE] [-p FIRST_PARAMETER]
                      [-n SECOND_PARAMETER]
code.py: error: argument -f is required
```

I can't comprehend how this is not defined - there is a file called `data` in the working directory, and from my understanding of the argument parser it doesn't care about file types when assigning input, so it should be assigning my `data.csv` as input. What gives?

Another option might be to just not use the argument parser, of course, and reading the file directly by commands, but I'd like to understand what I've done wrong here all the same.

Comment: how you run your script ? -f file_name is not optional, you need to put that argument while running your script.

Comment: I don't quite follow, what do you mean? Do I need to explicitly call -f?

Comment: how do u run your programe ?

Comment: you defined required=True for -f, so its mandatory.

Comment: Yes, you need to include -f and its value as a command line argument.  In your post you have a couple of function definitions but the following lines are not indented - please clean that up. http://dpaste.com/1536480/